# How to copy all but with exceptions

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to copy all elements, attributes and text of a tamplate match except the span class="mark" Note note.
source code

```
<p><img src="note.jpg"/><span class="mark">Note:</span> Text <span class="mark">Text</span> Text</p>
```

code should look like after conversion

```
<note>
<p>Text <span class="new">Text</span> Text</p></note>
```

my xls (it copys the span class="mark Note: also)

```
<xsl:template match="p[img/@src='note.pjpg']">
  <note>
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </p>
  </note>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing because:

1. `note.png` does not match `note.jpg`;
2. We don't see what other templates you have;
3. You say you want to copy everything except the `span` with `class`="new" -
   but that's **not** what your output shows.

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[img/@src='note.jpg']">
  <note>
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text() | span[@class='new']"/>
    </p>
  </note>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your input will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
   <p> Text <span class="new">Text</span> Text</p>
</note>
```

---

### Edit:

To keep everything except `span` with `class`="mark", do:

```
<xsl:template match="p[img/@src='note.jpg']">
  <note>
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::span[@class='mark'])]"/>
    </p>
  </note>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Edit 2:

To keep everything except the first `span` with `class`="mark", you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="p[img/@src='note.jpg']">
  <note>
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::span[@class='mark'][not(preceding-sibling::span[@class='mark'])])]"/>
    </p>
  </note>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You are right. I corrected my post. For the span[@class='new, I have a one template.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Is it possible to ingot only the first span class=mark?

Comment: @Olli I am not sure what you mean. Please edit your question and clarify. Or post a new one.

Comment: I changed my source code. There are more then on “span class=mark” elements. I just want to ignore the first one <span class="mark">Note:</span>